# Zend: ApacheDS and Windows ldap authentication issues

Tags: php, zend-framework, ldap, apacheds

I am trying to integrate ldap authentication to one of my Zend project.

I tried using ApacheDS and Windows ldap for windows 7. I can connect to the both ldap servers, but the authentication is not getting successful.

My development environment is:

- Windows 7
- IIS Server
- PHP & MSSQL
- ApacheDS or Windows LDAP

When I am using ApachDS I am getting the following error:

```
object(Zend_Auth_Result)#122 (3) {
  ["_identity":protected] => string(9) "mshakeel1"
  ["_messages":protected] => array(4) {
    [0] => string(28) "Account not found: mshakeel1"
    [1] => string(71) "0x20: No object found for: (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=mshakeel1))"
    [2] => string(188) "host=localhost,accountDomainName=foo.net,accountDomainNameShort=FOO,accountCanonicalForm=3,username=uid=admin,ou=system,password=*****,baseDn=ou=users,ou=system,bindRequiresDn=1,port=10389"
    [3] => string(104) "mshakeel1 authentication failed: 0x20: No object found for: (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=mshakeel1))"
  }
}
```

My application.ini is as follows for ApacheDS:

```
ldap.server.host = localhost
ldap.server.accountDomainName = foo.net
ldap.server.accountDomainNameShort = FOO
ldap.server.accountCanonicalForm = 3
ldap.server.username = "uid=admin,ou=system"
ldap.server.password = 'secret'
ldap.server.baseDn = "ou=users,ou=system"
ldap.server.bindRequiresDn = true
ldap.server.port = 10389
```

When I using Windows LDAP I am getting the following error:

```
object(Zend_Auth_Result)#122 (3) {
  ["_code":protected] => int(-3)
  ["_identity":protected] => string(9) "mshakeel1"
  ["_messages":protected] => array(4) {
    [0] => string(19) "Invalid credentials"
    [1] => string(129) "0x31 (Invalid credentials; 8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 2030, v1db0): W\mshakeel1"
    [2] => string(139) "host=ABC-PC-SH,useStartTls=,accountDomainName=w.net,accountDomainNameShort=W,accountCanonicalForm=3,baseDn=CN=Employees,DC=ABC,DC=SHGroup"
    [3] => string(162) "mshakeel1 authentication failed: 0x31 (Invalid credentials; 8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 2030, v1db0): W\mshakeel1"
  }
```

My application.ini is as follows for Windows LDAP:

```
ldap.server.host = ABC-PC-SH
ldap.server.useStartTls = false
ldap.server.accountDomainName = w.net
ldap.server.accountDomainNameShort = W
ldap.server.accountCanonicalForm = 3
ldap.server.baseDn = "CN=Employees,DC=ABC,DC=SHGroup"
```

Can anyone give me a hint to fix this please? Thanks.

Edit:
Thought add some more information..
My ApacheDS structure as shown below.

[image]

And my windows light weight AD service is as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following could be the reasons for the two errors you have mentioned when connecting your project to two different LDAP servers:

1. With ApacheDS server:
   Your project is querying a user entry with the object class: posixAccount (take a look at the query: (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=mshakeel1)) mentioned in the error message)

In order to solve this, you need to have an object with the given uid, and which is created with the object class: posixAccount. I am not sure if it is an object class supported by ApacheDS by default. If not, you need to add that object class to ApacheDS. You may refer: http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-introduce-custom-attributes-to.html for that.

Or else, you can change your project to construct the above search query with a supported object class in ApacheDS. (the default object class used to create user object is: inetOrgPerson) & make sure the searched entry is there in the ApacheDS server.

1. For Active Directory, from the error message, it seems like the credential provided for the user: ""mshakeel1" is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I am trying the alternatives you provided.

In addition could you please kindly tell me how can I set up the following parameters:

ldap.server.accountDomainName & ldap.server.accountDomainNameShort

Thanks